# Youtube API in android doesn't work

Tags: android, youtube-api

I followed the instruction of [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).But can not to make it work. Always got the "There was an error while playing" problem. Here is my steps:

1. Create the project in google play console
2. Enable the Youtube Data API for the project
3. Setup the credentials for the project

[image]

4. Import sample downloaded from google into Android studio
5. Change the package name to com.mydomain.youtubeapidemo

[image]

6. Change the developer key to the one in google play console

But I always get the "There was an error while playing" problem.

By the way, I'm using the following command to get the SHA1:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v

What could be the reason? Thanks for any suggestion.

**EDIT:**

I got the following error message in my console:

```
04-27 23:25:28.132    4995-5050/? E/WVMExtractor﹕ Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
04-27 23:25:28.961    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
04-27 23:25:28.984    4995-5058/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ getParameter(100663311) ERROR: 0x8000101a
\04-27 23:25:29.046    4995-5058/? E/SoftFFmpegVideo﹕ unsupported role: video_decoder.mpeg2
04-27 23:25:29.046    4995-5058/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ setParameter(16777239) ERROR: 0x80001001
04-27 23:25:29.046    4995-5058/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ getParameter(100663311) ERROR: 0x8000101a
04-27 23:25:29.046    4995-5058/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ getParameter(100663297) ERROR: 0x8000100e
04-27 23:25:29.046    4995-5058/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ OMX_GetExtensionIndex OMX.google.android.index.storeMetaDataInBuffers failed
04-27 23:25:29.161    4995-5146/? E/SoftAVC﹕ Decoder failed: -2
04-27 23:25:29.161    4995-5060/? E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
04-27 23:25:29.161    4995-5060/? E/ACodec﹕ signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
04-27 23:25:29.162    4995-5057/? E/MediaCodec﹕ Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 6
04-27 23:25:29.164    4995-5056/? E/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ Failed to dequeue input buffer for OMX.google.h264.decoder (err=-38)
04-27 23:25:29.164    4995-5049/? E/NuPlayer﹕ received error(0xffffffda) from video decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
04-27 23:25:29.164    2798-2871/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)
04-27 23:25:29.164    4995-5056/? E/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ failed to flush OMX.google.h264.decoder (err=-38)
04-27 23:25:29.164    4995-5049/? E/NuPlayer﹕ received error(0xffffffda) from video decoder, flushing(2), now shutting down
04-27 23:25:29.164    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-38)
04-27 23:25:29.165    2798-2815/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)
04-27 23:25:30.415    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
04-27 23:25:30.452    4995-5159/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ setParameter(1866465283) ERROR: 0x8000101a
04-27 23:25:30.452    4995-5157/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ OMX_GetExtensionIndex OMX.google.android.index.storeMetaDataInBuffers failed
04-27 23:25:30.452    4995-5157/? E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.h264.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648

04-27 23:25:31.983    4996-4996/? E/local_camera﹕ We have a problem with the hw connection 2 (No such file or directory)
04-27 23:25:31.984    2798-2871/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (100, 0)
04-27 23:25:31.984    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (100,0)
04-27 23:25:31.987      495-554/system_process E/AudioService﹕ Media server died.
04-27 23:25:32.068    5181-5181/? E/MonoPipe﹕ Failed to fetch local time frequency when constructing a MonoPipe (res = -32).  getNextWriteTimestamp calls will be non-functional
04-27 23:25:32.072    5181-5181/? E/SoundTriggerHwService﹕ couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
04-27 23:25:32.488      495-554/system_process E/AudioService﹕ Media server started.
04-27 23:25:33.279    5181-5194/? E/WVMExtractor﹕ Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
04-27 23:25:34.080    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set

04-27 23:25:34.133    5181-5200/? E/SoftFFmpegVideo﹕ unsupported role: video_decoder.mpeg2
04-27 23:25:34.133    5181-5200/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ setParameter(16777239) ERROR: 0x80001001    
04-27 23:25:34.231    5181-5281/? E/SoftAVC﹕ Decoder failed: -2
04-27 23:25:34.231    5181-5201/? E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
04-27 23:25:34.231    5181-5201/? E/ACodec﹕ signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
04-27 23:25:34.231    5181-5199/? E/MediaCodec﹕ Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 6
04-27 23:25:34.232    5181-5198/? E/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ Failed to dequeue output buffer for OMX.google.h264.decoder (err=-38)
04-27 23:25:34.233    5181-5193/? E/NuPlayer﹕ received error(0xffffffda) from video decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
04-27 23:25:34.233    5181-5198/? E/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ failed to flush OMX.google.h264.decoder (err=-38)
04-27 23:25:34.233    2798-2814/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)
04-27 23:25:34.233    5181-5193/? E/NuPlayer﹕ received error(0xffffffda) from video decoder, flushing(2), now shutting down
04-27 23:25:34.233    2798-2814/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)
04-27 23:25:34.233    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-38)
04-27 23:25:35.513    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
04-27 23:25:35.520    5181-5292/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ OMX_GetExtensionIndex OMX.google.android.index.storeMetaDataInBuffers failed
04-27 23:25:35.520    5181-5292/? E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.h264.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648
04-27 23:25:35.521    5181-5294/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ setParameter(1866465283) ERROR: 0x8000101a
04-27 23:25:35.525    5181-5295/? E/SoftAVC﹕ Decoder failed: -2
04-27 23:25:35.525    5181-5292/? E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
04-27 23:25:35.525    5181-5292/? E/ACodec﹕ signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
04-27 23:25:35.525    5181-5291/? E/MediaCodec﹕ Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 6
04-27 23:25:35.527    5181-5290/? E/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ Failed to dequeue input buffer for OMX.google.h264.decoder (err=-38)
04-27 23:25:35.527    5181-5285/? E/NuPlayer﹕ received error(0xffffffda) from video decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
04-27 23:25:35.527    2798-2871/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)
04-27 23:25:35.528    5181-5290/? E/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ failed to flush OMX.google.h264.decoder (err=-38)
04-27 23:25:35.528    5181-5285/? E/NuPlayer﹕ received error(0xffffffda) from video decoder, flushing(2), now shutting down
04-27 23:25:35.528    2798-2871/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)
04-27 23:25:35.531    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-38)
04-27 23:25:36.694    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
04-27 23:25:36.709    5181-5306/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ setParameter(1866465283) ERROR: 0x8000101a
04-27 23:25:36.710    5181-5307/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ OMX_GetExtensionIndex OMX.google.android.index.storeMetaDataInBuffers failed
04-27 23:25:36.710    5181-5307/? E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.h264.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648
04-27 23:25:36.722    5181-5310/? E/SoftAVC﹕ Decoder failed: -2
04-27 23:25:36.727    5181-5307/? E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
04-27 23:25:36.727    5181-5307/? E/ACodec﹕ signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
04-27 23:25:36.727    5181-5304/? E/MediaCodec﹕ Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 6
04-27 23:25:36.729    5181-5303/? E/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ Failed to dequeue input buffer for OMX.google.h264.decoder (err=-38)
04-27 23:25:36.730    5181-5299/? E/NuPlayer﹕ received error(0xffffffda) from video decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
04-27 23:25:36.733    2798-2871/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)
04-27 23:25:36.739    5181-5303/? E/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ failed to flush OMX.google.h264.decoder (err=-38)
04-27 23:25:36.740    5181-5299/? E/NuPlayer﹕ received error(0xffffffda) from video decoder, flushing(2), now shutting down
04-27 23:25:36.749    2798-2859/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -38)
04-27 23:25:36.766    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-38)
04-27 23:25:38.112    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
04-27 23:25:38.125    5181-5320/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ OMX_GetExtensionIndex OMX.google.android.index.storeMetaDataInBuffers failed
04-27 23:25:38.125    5181-5320/? E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.h264.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648
04-27 23:25:38.125    5181-5321/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ setParameter(1866465283) ERROR: 0x8000101a
04-27 23:25:38.131    5181-5324/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x60 in tid 5324 (peg.aac.decoder)
04-27 23:25:38.238        85-85/? E/DEBUG﹕ AM write failure (32 / Broken pipe)
04-27 23:25:38.294     495-1532/system_process E/SharedPreferencesImpl﹕ Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
04-27 23:25:38.321    5183-5183/? E/local_camera﹕ We have a problem with the hw connection 2 (No such file or directory)
04-27 23:25:38.321    5182-5182/? E/local_camera﹕ We have a problem with the hw connection 2 (No such file or directory)
04-27 23:25:38.323      495-554/system_process E/AudioService﹕ Media server died.
04-27 23:25:38.323    2798-2814/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (100, 0)
04-27 23:25:38.323    2798-2798/com.google.android.youtube.player E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (100,0)
04-27 23:25:38.412    5330-5330/? E/MonoPipe﹕ Failed to fetch local time frequency when constructing a MonoPipe (res = -32).  getNextWriteTimestamp calls will be non-functional
04-27 23:25:38.417    5330-5330/? E/SoundTriggerHwService﹕ couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
04-27 23:25:38.824      495-554/system_process E/AudioService﹕ Media server started.
```

Comment: is that the only error? does the log give more info

Comment: Are you running in an emulator or a device?

Comment: I didn't see any other error message. And it also doesn't work in device. How to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after I changed the video id in demo application. What I don't understand is it works if I put the video id from application to browser. Why the video in demo application doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

when you import the youtube android api demo ...
there you need to add your api key which one you have got from api store.

```
package com.examples.youtubeapidemo;

/**
 * Static container class for holding a reference to your YouTube Developer Key.
 */
public class DeveloperKey {

  /**
   * Please replace this with a valid API key which is enabled for the
   * YouTube Data API v3 service. Go to the
   * <a href="https://console.developers.google.com/">Google Developers Console</a>
   * to register a new developer key.
   */
  public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "Here you need to add your youtube api key ...dllk3m6SNbpRPHZLCly6Wq1pxM";

}
```

Comment: are you setting video url statically or fetching url from server and then applying here?